# python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully

Tags: python

I have just started learning about Python to control RIGOL DG4000 via python but always shows failure when installing Pyvxii11.

```
C:\Users\1013>pip install PyVXI11
Collecting PyVXI11
  Using cached PyVXI11-1.15.57.tar.gz (56 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2195 lines of output]
      'hg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      'rpcgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      'rpcgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      'rpcgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      'rpcgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      'rpcgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      'rpcgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      'rpcgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      'rpcgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      warning: cVXI11_3.pyx:600:10: cpdef variables will not be supported in Cython 3; currently they are no different from cdef variables
      warning: cVXI11_3.pyx:601:10: cpdef variables will not be supported in Cython 3; currently they are no different from cdef variables
      warning: cVXI11_3.pyx:602:10: cpdef variables will not be supported in Cython 3; currently they are no different from cdef variables
      warning: cVXI11_3.pyx:603:10: cpdef variables will not be supported in Cython 3; currently they are no different from cdef variables
      warning: cVXI11_3.pyx:604:10: cpdef variables will not be supported in Cython 3; currently they are no different from cdef variables
      warning: cVXI11_3.pyx:605:10: cpdef variables will not be supported in Cython 3; currently they are no different from cdef variables
      warning: cVXI11_3.pyx:606:10: cpdef variables will not be supported in Cython 3; currently they are no different from cdef variables
      warning: cVXI11_3.pyx:607:10: cpdef variables will not be supported in Cython 3; currently they are no different from cdef variables

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
              #print "dealloc GenericParms"
              if self.thisptr is NULL:
                  return
              with nogil:
                  xdr_free(<xdrproc_t> xdr_Device_GenericParms,
                           <c_xdr_free_argtype> self.thisptr)
                           ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      cVXI11_3.pyx:152:22: 'c_xdr_free_argtype' is not a type identifier

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          def __dealloc__(self):
              #print "dealloc GenericParms"
              if self.thisptr is NULL:
                  return
              with nogil:
                  xdr_free(<xdrproc_t> xdr_Device_GenericParms,
                          ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      cVXI11_3.pyx:151:21: Cannot convert 'xdrproc_t' to Python object

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...

          def __dealloc__(self):
              if self.thisptr is not NULL:
                  with nogil:
                      xdr_free(<xdrproc_t> xdr_Device_RemoteFunc,
                               <c_xdr_free_argtype> self.thisptr)
                               ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      cVXI11_3.pyx:203:26: 'c_xdr_free_argtype' is not a type identifier

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
              self.thisptr.progFamily=progFamily

          def __dealloc__(self):
              if self.thisptr is not NULL:
                  with nogil:
                      xdr_free(<xdrproc_t> xdr_Device_RemoteFunc,
                              ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      cVXI11_3.pyx:202:25: Cannot convert 'xdrproc_t' to Python object

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...

          def __dealloc__(self):
              if self.thisptr is NULL: return
              with nogil:
                  xdr_free(<xdrproc_t> xdr_Create_LinkResp,
                          <c_xdr_free_argtype>  self.thisptr)
                          ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

     
      cVXI11_3.pyx:1145:25: Cannot convert 'xdrproc_t' to Python object

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
                  with nogil:
                      xdr_free(<xdrproc_t> xdr_Device_ReadStbResp, <c_xdr_free_argtype> res)
                  raise RuntimeError
              rstb=res.stb
              with nogil:
                  xdr_free(<xdrproc_t> xdr_Device_ReadStbResp, <c_xdr_free_argtype> res)
                                                               ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      cVXI11_3.pyx:1149:58: 'c_xdr_free_argtype' is not a type identifier
```

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

What could be the cause of this? I really haven't found the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72879852/python-setup-py-egg-info-did-not-run-successfully-when-pip-install-mariadb