# mariadb_config not found installing mariadb package

Tags: python, pip, mariadb, setup.py

I try to install mariadb package on my ubuntu 20.04 and I get this message :

```
Collecting mariadb


Using cached mariadb-1.1.3.tar.gz (80 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-t71j4ld7/mariadb_85318304dde74615894ef8d77544330a/setup.py", line 26, in <module>
          cfg = get_config(options)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-t71j4ld7/mariadb_85318304dde74615894ef8d77544330a/mariadb_posix.py", line 63, in get_config
          cc_version = mariadb_config(config_prg, "cc_version")
        File "/tmp/pip-install-t71j4ld7/mariadb_85318304dde74615894ef8d77544330a/mariadb_posix.py", line 28, in mariadb_config
          raise EnvironmentError(
      OSError: mariadb_config not found.
      
      This error typically indicates that MariaDB Connector/C, a dependency which must be preinstalled,
      is not found.
      If MariaDB Connector/C is not installed, see installation instructions
      at: https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/wiki/install.md.
      If MariaDB Connector/C is installed, either set the environment variable MARIADB_CONFIG or edit
      the configuration file 'site.cfg' to set the 'mariadb_config' option to the file location of the
      mariadb_config utility.
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I found many subject and answer about this topic like update and upgrade the system, upgrade my pip version or install packages like libmariadbclient-dev, setuptools or libmysqlclient-dev.

I installed libmariadb-dev on my system too but none of these solutions works for me.

python3 --version : Python 3.8.10

pip --version : pip 22.1.2

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

It is not enough to install libmariadb-dev, you also need to install libmariadb (afaik it is libmariadb3 on focal), since mariadb-config binary is not part of the dev package.

`sudo apt-get install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev`.

Another option would be to install the server package, which also contains MariaDB Connector/C.

Comment: Thank you for this try and your're probably right but it was already installed. I got a new information.
I success the install without virtual env but it failed in my venv... ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem while installing `termcolor`. And, found the solution at [this site](https://www.partitionwizard.com/partitionmanager/python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1.html). (*i am no way related to that site. Just browsed it.*).

### For me, using

```bash
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

worked well. The problem was that, I was using an older version of `setuptools` which was not able to install the packages with latest updates.

Comment: How is this related to the question? Did you have the same problem and your answer solved it?

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem, and this solved it.

Comment: I had the problem one more time and this solution didn't work.

Comment: I was having this problem installing the pillow module from source into a python3.8 virtual environment on an old Debian-based system (raspbian).  'pip --install upgrade setuptools' upgraded my setuptools from version 56 to 65, and it fixed this error.  I had more errors to deal with, but it got me farther into the build process for the pillow module than I had gotten to that point. (so that's an upvote from me.)

Comment: This answer is probably addressing the generic error message `egg_info did not run successfully` instead of the specific error that the OP was getting.

Answer (score 0):

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**: upgrade all other packages and THEN install the package in question.

I came across similar errors when upgrading python packages:

```
pip3 freeze --local | egrep -v '^\-e|@' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs pip install --user -U --no-deps
```

but several packages wouldn't install and throw the error:
`python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.`
So I excluded the packages from the upgrade:

```
pip3 freeze --local | egrep -v '^\-e|@' | cut -d = -f 1 | grep -v atomicwrites | grep -v drep | grep -v gffutils | grep -v hapROH | grep -v pyfaidx | grep -v pygtrie | grep -v python-igraph | grep -v pytools | grep -v rpy2 | grep -v vamb | xargs pip install --user -U --no-deps
```

**After** the upgrade of all upgradable packages I could install the problem children:

```
echo -e "atomicwrites\ndrep\ngffutils\nhapROH\npyfaidx\npygtrie\npython-igraph\npytools\nrpy2\nvamb"| xargs pip3 install --user --upgrade --no-deps
```

Comment: I had the problem one more time and this solution didn't work.

Comment: the same error? is mariadb installed? are you still using ubuntu 20.04? did you update all pip packages before?

Comment: This answer is probably addressing the generic error message `egg_info did not run successfully` instead of the specific error that the OP was getting.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by installing the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadb3 libmariadb-dev
```

then run this command:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```